# Bounding $\sin(\pi z)$ away from $0$ on a circular contour in $\Bbb C$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, inequality, optimization, hyperbolic-functions

I'm currently trying to show the following:

> Let $C_R$ be the circle of radius $R=N+\frac{1}{2}$ for some $N\in\Bbb N$. Then $$\lim_{R\to\infty}\ \int_{C_R}\frac{1}{z^2\sin(\pi z)}\,dz=0.$$

This will follow immediately if we can prove $\sin(\pi z)$ is bounded away from zero on the contour. To that end, I've shown $|\sin(\pi z)|\geq1$ for $z\in C_R$ is equivalent to proving the inequality

$$\cosh(x)\geq 2+\cos\left(\sqrt{(2\pi R)^2-x^2}\right)$$

for $-2\pi R\leq x\leq2\pi R$.

This brings me to my question:

> How can we prove this inequality?

I've thought of trying to use Taylor series here, but $x$ isn't necessarily close to $0$. I also thought of this as a Calculus I style problem (after all, we're just minimizing a single-variable function), but the derivative was too convoluted to reasonably work with unless I missed something.

The plots that I know how to make on Mathematica agree with my computations, so I have reason to believe this is the correct idea, I'm just not sure how to formally prove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,  $|\sin(z)| \ge 1$ does hold on circles with radius $N+1/2$ centered at the origin ($N$ a positive integer), see the second part of this answer.

In order to get *some* positive lower bound on those circles one can proceed as follows. The idea is to distinguish whether $z$ is “close to the real axis” or not.

For $z = x+iy$ with $x, y \in \Bbb R $ is
$$
|\sin(\pi z)|^2 = \sin^2(\pi x) + \sinh^2(\pi y) \, .
$$

If $|y| \ge 1/4$ then
$$
 |\sin(\pi z)| \ge |\sinh(\pi y)| \ge \sinh( \frac \pi 4) > 0 \, .
$$

And if $|z| = N + 1/2$ with $|y| \le 1/4$ then
$$
 N + \frac 14 \le |z| - |y| \le |x| \le N + \frac 12
$$
so that
$$
|\sin(\pi z)| \ge |\sin(\pi x) | \ge \sin( \frac \pi 4) > 0 \, .
$$

This proves $|\sin(\pi z)| \ge \sin( \frac \pi 4) = 1/\sqrt 2$ for all $z$ on the circle.

---

The (sharp) bound $|\sin(z)| \ge 1$ on the circles with radius $N+1/2$ requires a bit more work. We have

$$
\begin{align}
|\sin(\pi z)|^2 &= \sin^2(\pi x) + \sinh^2(\pi y) \\
 &= \cosh^2(\pi y) - \cos^2(\pi x) \\
 &= \frac 12 \bigl( \cosh(2\pi y) - \cos(2\pi x)\bigr)
\end{align}
$$
and the goal is to prove that
$$ \tag{*}
\cosh(2\pi y) - \cos(2\pi x) \ge 2
$$
for $x^2+y^2 = (N+1/2)^2$ and all positive integers $N$. (Which is the same inequality that you got.)

It suffices to consider non-negative $x$. The idea is indeed to use Taylor series, but not at $x=0$ but at $x=N+1/2$.

With $d = N+1/2 - x$ is
$$
 0 \le d \le N + \frac 12 \, ,\\
 x = N + \frac 12 - d \, ,\\
 y^2 = 2 d \left( N + \frac 12 \right) - d^2 \, .
$$

Then
$$
 \cosh(2\pi y) \ge 1 + \frac{(2 \pi y)^2}{2!} = 1 + 2 \pi^2 \bigl(2d \left( N + \frac 12 \right) -  d^2 \bigr)
$$
and
$$
 - \cos(2\pi x) = \cos(2 \pi d) \ge 1 - \frac{(2 \pi d)^2}{2!}
 = 1 - 2 \pi^2 d^2 \, .
$$
Adding the last two inequalities gives
$$
\cosh(2\pi y)- \cos(2\pi x) \ge 2 + 2 \pi^2 \bigl(2d \left( N + \frac 12 \right) -  2d^2 \bigr) \\
 = 2 + 4 \pi^2 d \bigl( N + \frac 12 - d\bigr) \ge 2 \, .
$$
This proves $(*)$ and we are done.

Comment: Thanks, Martin! I understand your solution and have upvoted it accordingly. Do you know how to prove the bound $|\sin(\pi z)|\geq1$ (which, if Mathematica is to be believed), would be the tight bound). I do appreciate your answer but want to wait to see if you (or another) can help me prove the best bound.

Comment: This looks great! I just read through it entirely and will now work things out on paper. Thank you, @Martin!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|\sin z|^2= \sin^2 x \cosh^2 y + \cos^2 x \sinh^2 y$ is a convex combination of  $\sinh^2 y$ and $\cosh ^2 y$ (whose convex weights are $\cos^2 x$ and $\sin^2 x$). Thus it is straightforward to bound this expression  on horizontal and vertical line segments where either $y>0$ is constant or $x$ is constant.

*The sneaky trick is to deform $C$ onto such a grid, then estimate the integral.* Of course it is best to use $x= (N+(1/2)) \pi$ as your first vertical segment, because there we know that the convex combination places all its weight purely on the larger term $\cosh^2 y \geq 1$.